# CentOS 7 how to stop / start Gnome desktop from command line

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, centos7, gnome, gnome-shell

I have remote server running under CentOS 7, usually it's enough to operate using SSH CLI - but sometimes I need a graphic access, so I installed Gnome Desktop there too.

But how to stop or start Gnome Desktop ? Especially because gnome-shell eats CPU when I don't need Gnome.

It seems strange but 3 pages of Google search did not help.
I'm afraid there are no a simple solution here like

```
service gnome stop | start
```

So thanks in advance for any hint or howto !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

But the solution was simple.
First of all - check if you GDM service is running.

```
service gdm status
```

If not - start it to make active.
(my case service gdm was loaded but inactive and it causes a confusing)
After that I just stopped gdm service

```
service gdm stop
```

and checked any Gnome processes

```
ps aux | grep gnome
```

an output is empty, Gnome desktop gone until started again by

```
service gdm start
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 I had to do the following:   
sudo systemctl stop gdm3  . 
To disable at startup I did:   sudo systemctl disable gdm3

Comment: I think the preferred ways on systemd are `systemctl start graphical.target` to start and `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` to stop any graphical-only services.